# A TryGet procedure for php arrays

Tags: php, null, key, associative-array

Every time I have to get an element that might not exist from an associative array in PHP, I have to write everything twice.

```
$myvar = array_key_exists($array, 'key') ? $array['key'] : NULL;
```

I feel there is a much simpler way to do this.

Comment: I really have never seen the point of `array_key_exists()`. `isset($array['key'])` has always worked fine for me. But I imagine you are looking for the PHP equivalent of Javascript's `var myVar = otherVar || null;`, and I'm afraid you're already looking at it. It is possible to do `$myVar = $array['key'] ?: NULL;` in >=5.3, but this will trigger a warning if it's not set and won't work if `$array['key']` has a falsey value. Yes, `array_key_exists()` will return true when the key has a value of `NULL`, which `isset()` doesn't - but in this instance you just initialise to `NULL` anyway.

Comment: @DaveRandom in the weird case when you have an array with `NULL` values, `isset($array['key'])` returns `false` while `array_key_exists('key', $array)` returns `true`

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós I know I just realised that and added a note to my comment. But in this case it makes no difference - the value is being initialised to `NULL` as a fallback anyway. I can't actually think of a use case for knowing whether a key is set with a `NULL` value - `NULL` means "has no value" so to all intents and purposes the key *doesn't* exist. IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what you mean ... I prefer this approach:

```
$myvar = isset($array['key']) ? $array['key'] : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

same way ,you must make a judgement for it existence,

```
$myvar=isset($array['key'])?$array['key']:"";    
$myvar=$array['key']||$myvar="";
```

you can make a try,hope that it is useful to you ~~~~

Comment: This generates an `E_NOTICE` event if the key doesn't exist